# WooCommerce - New Order Email - Add Shipping Address

Tags: woocommerce

I am looking to add the shipping address from the order to the New Order email. Can anyone please provide detailed information on how to do so? I am pretty new to editing functions.php, hooks, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this
you can comment out the conditional part if you want to have it on customer email as well.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'woocommerce_add_shipping_address_to_admin_emails', 15, 2 );
function woocommerce_add_shipping_address_to_admin_emails( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    if ( $is_admin_email ) {
        echo '<p><strong>Shipping Address:</strong> ' . $order->get_formatted_shipping_address() . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, does this go in functions.php, and if so where?

Comment: Yeah in the functions.php file, let me know if it works as needed

Comment: Thanks! I edited just a bit to add line breaks above the Shipping Address header and to move the start of the get_formatted_shipping_address to the next line. Other than that, works great!!

Comment: Great, please check this answer.

Comment: why did you check `$is_admin_email`? is this necessary?

Comment: @nyconing this is to restrict it to admin emails only, it's not necessary, you can remove it to add the info the admin and customer emails

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this snippet. It works perfectly! Here is a version which separates header (shipping address) from content:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'woocommerce_add_shipping_address_to_admin_emails', 15, 2 );
function woocommerce_add_shipping_address_to_admin_emails( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    if ( $is_admin_email ) {
       $header = '<p><strong>Shipping Address:</strong> ' . '</p>';
        $shippingInfo = '<p>' . $order->get_formatted_shipping_address() . '</p>';

        echo $header;
        echo $shippingInfo; 
    }
}
```